# Floating date and time in ics file not working for yahoo calendar

Tags: javascript, ajax, calendar, timezone, icalendar

I am creating a calendar event for Google calendar, Apple calendar and Yahoo calendar. The event is specific to each individual customer and based on their address it will happen a specific time so we don't need any timezone conversion. The `.ics` file I created is displaying the time correctly for Google and Apple calendar but is displaying incorrect time for Yahoo calendar.

So I have created an ics file with `DTSTART:20190415T154500` and `DTEND:20190415T16450` ([as specified](https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/dateTime.html) date with local time) with no time zone specified. This works fine for Apple and Google calendar, but in the case of Yahoo it's displaying `Mon, 15 Apr, 11:45 AM - 12:45 PM` even though my Yahoo calendars time zone is same as my Google calendar. Below is my `.ics` file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR  
VERSION:2.0  
PRODID:-//ZContent.net//Zap Calendar 1.0//EN  
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN  
METHOD:PUBLISH  
BEGIN:VEVENT  
SUMMARY:Specialist arrival window  
UID:d5497571-a7fe-49e2-b0a5-d619e7f5c73a
DTSTART:20190415T154500  
DTEND:20190415T164500  
LOCATION:101 XYZ BLDG 1\, SAN FRANCISCO\,CA\,94098    
DESCRIPTION:Thanks for choosing our service!   
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html><body>Thanks for choosing our service.<br> 
 <br> Have to reschedule? sigin to change your appointment day and time. </body> 
 </html>  
END:VEVENT  
END:VCALENDAR
```

Expectation is that irrespective of the time zone user should get the time as Monday, April 15⋅3:45 – 4:45pm. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just in case - try validating the ics file in the ics validators.Above is probably a cut and paste error but the DTSTART is not on a new line and it doesn't look like the X-ALT DESC is folded correctly (supposed to be CR:F then a space?).

Comment: Also I know you said that you understand and are deliberately using floating dates BUT consider is these are actual appointments, not say a reminder (eg to take a pill") AND the person is travelling, then their timezones may be changing and they may prefer to have the appointment correctly reflect wherever they going to be at the time of the appointment.   And that may fix your problem?

Comment: @anmari This is kind of appointment time that will be sent to the customer and it will be at their address ,so it has to be a fixed time . Also you are right its a copy paste issue here ,the point is while apple,outlook and google are correctly considering these as "floating" time yahoo is ignoring it totally.

Comment: If it's a yahoo bug or non supported feature, you might have to get around it.  As a debug - to see if it's the file or that yahoo doesn't support try issuing in UTC.  It sounds like you are issuing floating datetime as a convenience to yourself and could achieve same effect using the timezone of the address at which the appointment will be.  So if Yahoo doesn't support floating (I have no idea whether it does or not ), then just convert to UTC time and issue that.

Comment: @anmari ,actually there are multiple slots that are available for the appointments and it doesn't matter at what timezone the customer is we need to have same set of appointments for every customer ,So we cant really use customer's timezone that's why we need floating time..

Comment: So if you wish to test what yahoo is doing, use the c/o Timezone then.  If it’s fixed to a location then a Timezone is relevant.  While one can get away with using floating times for people who aren’t traveling, it’s not the 100% best solution .  Imagine one of your customers has appointment for 10 am in the companies Timezone.  They’ve added it to their calendar.  Now they are travelling and the partner at home is going to handle the appointment at the fixed address.  The traveling person may now have the ‘wrong’ time.  They may forget to advise the home person.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the date-times to UTC (subtracting the -7 hours timezone offset of San Fransisco from UTC) and suffixing them with a `Z`? Something like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR  
VERSION:2.0  
PRODID:-//ZContent.net//Zap Calendar 1.0//EN  
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN  
METHOD:PUBLISH  
BEGIN:VEVENT  
SUMMARY:Specialist arrival window  
UID:d5497571-a7fe-49e2-b0a5-d619e7f5c73a
DTSTART:20190415T084500Z
DTEND:20190415T094500Z
LOCATION:101 XYZ BLDG 1\, SAN FRANCISCO\,CA\,94098    
DESCRIPTION:Thanks for choosing our service!   
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html><body>Thanks for choosing our service.<br> 
 <br> Have to reschedule? sigin to change your appointment day and time. </body> 
 </html>  
END:VEVENT  
END:VCALENDAR
```